# Non-modal JDialog not displaying content?

Tags: java, swing

I am building a server program that receives a socket connection from a client.  When the program initiates the server, I would like to display a dialog that displays "Waiting for connection..." as it waits.  Once the connection is received, I would like to programatically close the window.  As I do not want to block the execution of the program as it waits for the socket connection, I have used a non-modal dialog to display the message.  This works, except that the dialog does not display the text that I would like it to.  The dialog title displays fine, but the message pane does not.  Why is this?  I have tried several different ways to accomplish this, including the code below, all to no avail.

```
public class AboutDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener 
{
    public AboutDialog(JFrame parent, String title, String message) 
    {
        super(parent, title, false);

        if (parent != null) 
        {
            Dimension parentSize = parent.getSize(); 
            Point p = parent.getLocation(); 
            setLocation(p.x + parentSize.width / 4, p.y + parentSize.height / 4);
        }

        JPanel messagePane = new JPanel();
        messagePane.add(new JLabel(message));
        getContentPane().add(messagePane);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack(); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        setVisible(false); 
        dispose(); 
    }
}
```

Just in case my explanation isn't clear, I pass "Waiting for connection..." into the AboutDialog constructor as the message parameter.  Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Your above code worked in my case. Can you show me the line which actually calls the constructor ?

Comment: I am doing nothing more than: AboutDialog ad = new AboutDialog(new JFrame(), "Network", "Waiting for connection...");

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not opening (and closing) your dialog in the event dispatch thread (using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` from the main/listening thread).

That said, having a GUI for a server application is probably not a good idea anyway. Server apps frequently run on headless servers, and are frequently started as services/daemons. Using a log file is probably a better idea than using a GUI.